# Show a gif icon in point GeoServer SLD

Tags: geoserver, wms, symbology, sld, svg

How to show a gif image for a point in GeoServer SLD like blinking point?

I found [here](https://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/animate-your-maps-with-geoserver-animator-tool/) animated wms layer. Please help me.

I tried SVG Icon. Its working without animation. My svg code is

```
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 320 320">
        <path
            fill="#FF0000" stroke="#FF0000"
            d="M40,50a10,10 0 1,0 20,0a10,10 0 1,0 -20,0">
            <animate
                attributeType="XML"
                attributeName="fill"
                values="#900;#f00;#800;#800"
                dur="0.8s"
                repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            </path>
 </svg>
```

Comment: The example doesn't seem to match your question

Comment: An alternative would be to use wfs and to use an animated marker in OpenLayers (or else)

Answer (score 2):

In general (in answer to *"How to show a gif image for a point in GeoServer SLD"*) to have an image in an SLD you need to place the image in a location that can be read by the SLD/GeoServer.

So for example in the following GetMap request to a GeoServer WMS, where an external SLD is applied to a remote service:

[image: GeoServer WMS with external SLD]

through the following request:

```
http://maps.gns.cri.nz/geoserver/gns/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&bbox=-47.65,165.87,-33.89,179.27&width=800&height=800&srs=EPSG:4272&format=image/png&sld=http://ogcdev.bgs.ac.uk/erml/MineralOccurrenceForGSgerm1.sld&
```

The [external SLD](http://ogcdev.bgs.ac.uk/erml/MineralOccurrenceForGSgerm1.sld) references an image:

```
<PointSymbolizer>
    <Graphic>
        <ExternalGraphic>
            <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://ogcdev.bgs.ac.uk/erml/burg02.svg"/>
            <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
        </ExternalGraphic>
        <Size>10</Size>
    </Graphic>
</PointSymbolizer>
```

In this case the image (burg02.svg) and the SLD are in the same public folder and the server is able to parse them.

To the more specific *"like blinking point"* I think the answer is it's not possible, because as part of the GetMap request GeoServer reads the SLD, applies it to the data and creates a single image.  So in the map image (above) from a point data source there is no individual burg02.svg image, there is instead an image of the image.

Comment: ya i tried svg it's working without animation. I want to animate like flashing.

Comment: In a WMS I don't think it's possible to have individual animated points. That's not what your example is showing. You may be able to animate the whole map image.

Comment: my example not correct but i want to animate some points in a wms layer with svg animation or any other technique. Is it Possible ?

Comment: The only way I could see that working would be if every point was it's own layer.

Comment: We can make a rule for those points to be animated!

Comment: In the SVG yes but it is the input format, not the output format

Comment: I'm n't understood, What is input format and output format in SVG icons code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78625/discussion-between-hyma-and-nmtoken).